# What is the best way to write custom iterator in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, rvalue-reference

I used to write pointer like structures(like smart pointer, iterator etc) using a conversion constructor , which allows one way non-const to const conversion. This style prevents code duplication for const/non-const version.
e.g.

```
template<class T>
struct ptr_like
{
  using self_type = ptr_like<T>;
  using nonconst_self = ptr_like<remove_const<T>>;
  ptr_like() : ptr_(){}
  //a friendship may be needed to access private member
  ptr_like(nonconst_self const& rhs) : ptr_(rhs.ptr_){//implementation} 1)
  //ptr_like(ptr_like const& rhs) = default; 2)
  T* ptr_;//exposition only
}; 
ptr_like<int> x1,x2 = x1;//converting constructor
ptr_like<int const> x3,x4 = x3;//default constructor
//ptr_like<int> x5 = x3; //error as intended
ptr_like<int const> x6 = x1;//converting constructor, allowed conversion.
```

However as in c++11 `is_trivially_copy_constructible` is false for `ptr_like<T>` , while true for `ptr_like<T const>`, in effect using `ptr_like<T>` as a member variable of a class removes default move constructor (as it has non-trivial copy constructor, and no move constructor available), while it is perfect to use `ptr_like<T const>` as member of a class as it has trivial copy constructor.
e.g.

```
struct holder
{
 ptr_like<int> p;//(3
 holder(holder const&) = delete;
 holder(holder&&) = default; 
};
is_move_constructible<holder>() == false
std::vector<holder> v; 
holder h;
v.push_back(std::move(h)); //this fails as no move constructor possible.
```

providing a default copy constructor for `ptr_like` (as in 2) is also useless, as it is already implements a copy constructor for `ptr_like<T>`

This effect can be seen in many boost classes (e.g. `boost::circular_buffer<T>::iterator`) where storing them in a class disables move constructor for that class. And moreover it silently does copy when copy constructor is not deleted.

So, the question is, what is the best way to write pointer like classes with duplicating code in c++11?
(And as an auxiliary question, I am searching for the reason why move constructor is disabled for a class when a member variable has non-trivial copy constructor)

Comment: Somehow i fail to see the connection between the title and the contents.

Comment: I agree with RedX, but Boost.Iterator.

Comment: "And as an auxiliary question, I am searching for the reason why move constructor is disabled for a class when a member variable has non-trivial copy constructor" If you have another question to ask, then ask it *separately*. As for the answer, it's obvious. If you have to implement a copy constructor for your class, then you obviously need to think about how to implement a move constructor. Besides; you have the `= default` syntax if you just want to use the regular one, so it's not like it's hard to use the compiler-generated one.